# DidFailLoadError

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to make a alert when the internet connection failed.

```
-(void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" 
                                                    message:@"Can't connect. Please check your internet Connection" 
                                                   delegate:self 
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];


}
```

.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface wedstrijden : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;

    }

@end
```

Code for website html

```
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];

    UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height - 20.f)];
    [webView setAutoresizingMask:(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth)];
    [webView loadRequest:request];
    [self.view addSubview:webView];
```

No error, no alert .. nothing?!

Web connected to: http://cl.ly/441B1m2Y0M0c2b0n1h2J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are not setting the delegate for your UIWebView. Add this line before the `[webView loadRequest]` statement:

```
webView.delegate = self;
```

And your interface declaration for your .h file should be:

```
@interface wedstrijden : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate> { ...
```